# Convert from K to thousand (1000) in R

Tags: r

first post so please be nice. I am learning my way through R and wanted to know if there's a quick way of converting from k to thousands. For instance, if I have 1.4k it would convert to 1400 or if it is 14k it would be 14000. I have found articles converting the other way but not like this. Would very much appreciate your input. Cheerio, Mari

Comment: More info is needed to provide a quality response, like what else is in the vector besides these two values.  Please read about how to ask in the [help].

Comment: HI, they are just a vector of numbers, if they are over 1000 they are represented with k. There are no other conditions, other than the ones I've described. The below answers my question from @kunal pun. Thanks!

Comment: There is an example of this at the end of section 3 of the gsubfn package vignette which not only handles K (kilo) but also G (giga) and P (peta) and is extendable in an obvious way to as many suffixes as you like:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/vignettes/gsubfn.pdf

Comment: `dat <- c("100k", "20K", "15K", "30") ; as.numeric(gsubfn::gsubfn("[kK]$", list(k = "e3", K = "e3"), dat))` to show the utility of Gabor's pkg (for others searching tho find this question).

Comment: You could just use sub in that case.  Suggest you look at the original example instead which is not so easily handled using a simple sub.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another way similar to what @RichardScriven has suggested:

```
x <- c("1.4k", "14k")

as.numeric(sub("k", "e3", x, fixed = TRUE))

## [1]  1400 14000
```