# How to replace string from numeric value in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains the number of app installers, the data recorded with units `M` and `K`, like: `19M`, `199K`.

How to replace the prefixes with their values to convert values to numeric.

`k` to `e+3`

`M` to `e+6`

Comment: strsplit(), type.convert(), and switch() will be your friends

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972571/changing-million-billion-abbreviations-into-actual-numbers-ie-5-12m-5-120-0 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013217/convert-from-billion-to-million-and-vice-versa and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806215/convert-from-k-to-thousand-1000-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: For values that have non-integer values.

```
x <- c("19M","20K","1K", "1.25M", "1.5K"); x
x <- sub("M", "e6", x); x
x <- sub("K", "e3", x); x
as.numeric(x)
[1] 19000000    20000     1000  1250000     1500
```

---

For integer values, the following is sufficient.

```
x <- c("19M","20K","1K")

x <- sub("M","000000", x)
x <- sub("K","000", x)
as.numeric(x)
```

---

```
1.9e+07 2.0e+04 1.0e+03
```

Comment: 1.5K is not 1.5e+00