# Binary operations in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rvest

I have a small question regarding binary operations in a dataframe. Here I have a dataframe and I want to create a new column `PerWeek` which is the result when taking `Gross` divided by `Weeks`, and I am wondering how can I do it since `Gross` elements are not numeric.

```
boxoffice = function(){
  url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/boxoffice"
  read_table = read_html("https://www.imdb.com/chart/boxoffice")
  movie_table = html_table(html_nodes(read_table, "table")[[1]])
  Name = movie_table[2]
  Gross = movie_table[4]
  Weeks = movie_table[5]
  BoxOffice = 
  for (i in 1:10){
    PerWeek = movie_table[4][i] %/% movie_table[5][i]
  }
  df = data.frame(Name,BoxOffice,PerWeek)
  return(df)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Gross` value always in millions, you can get the numbers from it and multiply by `1e6` to get amount in millions and then divide by `Weeks`.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/boxoffice"
read_table = read_html("https://www.imdb.com/chart/boxoffice")
movie_table = html_table(html_nodes(read_table, "table")[[1]])
movie_table <- movie_table[-c(1, ncol(movie_table))]
movie_table %>% mutate(per_week_calc = readr::parse_number(Gross) * 1e6/Weeks)


#                  Title Weekend   Gross Weeks per_week_calc
#1                Onward  $10.5M  $60.3M     2      30150000
#2       I Still Believe   $9.5M   $9.5M     1       9500000
#3             Bloodshot   $9.3M  $10.5M     1      10500000
#4     The Invisible Man   $6.0M  $64.4M     3      21466667
#5              The Hunt   $5.3M   $5.8M     1       5800000
#6    Sonic the Hedgehog   $2.6M $145.8M     5      29160000
#7          The Way Back   $2.4M  $13.4M     2       6700000
#8  The Call of the Wild   $2.2M  $62.1M     4      15525000
#9                 Emma.   $1.4M  $10.0M     4       2500000
#10    Bad Boys for Life   $1.1M $204.3M     9      22700000
```

If you have data in billions or thousands you can refer

[Changing Million/Billion abbreviations into actual numbers? ie. 5.12M -> 5,120,000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972571/changing-million-billion-abbreviations-into-actual-numbers-ie-5-12m-5-120-0) and [Convert from K to thousand (1000) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806215/convert-from-k-to-thousand-1000-in-r)

Comment: Is there an option to add the `per_week_calc` to the dataframe besides `mutate()`, since my I want my dataframe to consist of `Title`, `Gross` and `per_week_calc`

Comment: @warmsoda Sorry, I didn't get you. You can use `select` to include only specific columns in final dataframe. `movie_table %>% mutate(per_week_calc = readr::parse_number(Gross) * 1e6/Weeks) %>% select(Title, Gross, per_week_calc)` if you want that.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I used `transmute()` instead of `mutate()` and got what I wanted.