# Trouble following Scatter Plot Implementation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble following along with an example provided by my professor. We're meant to follow along provided examples to understand the code and how the implementation goes and then do a different assignment based on topics covered in examples.

I'm having problems implementing a Scatter plot on the example. The code uses the Adult dataset from the UCI machine learning repository and has the following code.

```
#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

#import data
adult = read.csv("adult.DATA", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
summary(adult)
colnames(adult)

#remove similar columns and rename
adult_trim = adult[,-c(3,4,11,12)]
names(adult_trim) <- c("Age", "WorkClass", "Education", "Marital.Status", "Occupation", "Relationship", "Race",
                   "Sex", "Hours.per.Week", "Native.Country", "Income")

#remove empty values & Race/NativeCountry
adult_trim <- adult_trim[rowSums(adult_trim == "?") ==0, -c(7,10), drop = FALSE]
```

The problem is in the following scatterplot. The data doesnt have any header values for column names so it imports as v1,v2,... etc.

```
adult$V4 = as.factor(as.character(adult$V4))
levels(adult$V4)
plot(
  jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4),0.5) ~ jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4), 0.5),
  data = adult_trim,
  xlab = "Income",
  ylab = "Education",
  pch = 19, 
  cex = 1, 
  bty = "n",
  xlim = c(1:2),
  col = rgb(180,0,180,30, maxColorValue = 255)
 )
```

When trying to implement this plot on my machine it just gives me an error.

```
Warning message:
In plot.formula(jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4), 0.5) ~ jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4),  :
  c("the formula 'jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4), 0.5) ~ jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4), ' 
 is treated as 'jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4), 0.5) ~ 1'", "the formula '    0.5)' 
 is treated as 'jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4), 0.5) ~ 1'")
```

its supposed to look like this graph but with education https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPfhX.png but I'm just getting the error. Also is there any reason this decides to use the original "adult" instead of "adult_trim" ?

Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Also is there any reason this decides to use the original "adult" instead of "adult_trim"?

It uses the original `adult` instead of `adult_trim` because in the `jitter` function you explicitly specify `adult$V4`. Your use of `adult` there overrides the `data = adult_trim` argument later on. With the `data` argument provided, you should just use the column name and rely on the data argument to point `plot` to the correct data frame to look in to find the column.

> The problem is in the following scatterplot. The data doesnt have any header values for column names so it imports as v1,v2,... etc.

But you also show code to replace the default column names in `adult_trim`. After you run the line

```
names(adult_trim) <- c("Age", "WorkClass", "Education", "Marital.Status", "Occupation", "Relationship", "Race",
                   "Sex", "Hours.per.Week", "Native.Country", "Income")
```

then `adult_trim` has those column names, and it doesn't remember anything about `V1, V2, V3, V4,` etc.

When you use a formula (with `~`) inside `plot()`, you should use `yvalues ~ xvalues`. You have

```
jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4),0.5) ~ jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4), 0.5)
```

which uses `jitter(as.numeric(adult$V4),0.5)` for both x and y values, uses the wrong data frame (overriding the `data =` argument), and an old column name. I would instead try

```
plot(
  jitter(as.numeric(Education), 0.5) ~ jitter(as.numeric(Income), 0.5),
  data = adult_trim,
  xlab = "Income",
  ylab = "Education",
  pch = 19, 
  cex = 1, 
  bty = "n",
  xlim = c(1:2),
  col = rgb(180,0,180,30, maxColorValue = 255)
 )
```

---

It's also too bad that people are still teaching beginners base plots instead of ggplot. What I'd really recommend is

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(adult_trim, aes(x = Income, y = Education)) +
  geom_point(position = "jitter", color = "hotpink3", alpha = 0.2)
```

---

And lastly, there are important differences between **Warnings** (which you code shows) and **Errors** (which you say you have, but don't). A *warning* means your code executed, but there may have been problems, so it warns you to check carefully. An *error* means that your code could not be executed - nothing was changed, you need to fix it before it will run.

Comment: Thank you I was able to get it working. If you don't mind I encountered another problem.  The same code and everything is used but then it executes "adult_trim$Income_Binary = ifelse(adult_trim$Income == ">50K", 1, 0)" and just fills the vector with only 0s and doesn't do the comparison correctly. Any idea as to what it might be? By default the code has Income as levels 1 & 2 and needs to convert to binary for training the dataset

Comment: Numbers in R don't have quotes and letters in them. (Except for `e`, which is used for scientific notation.) "50k" is a character string, not a number, and character strings are ordered alphabetically. If you want to treat income as a number, you need to covert it to numeric. [Here's a question where someone had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36806215/903061).